# Generate multine line YAML with Ansible jinja filter to_yaml

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Using Ansible, `to_yaml` jinja filter, i want to generate the following YAML encoded string:

```
data: |
   hello: world
   bonjour: monde
```

Example:

```
      - set_fact:
          my_data:
            data: |
              hello: world
              bonjour: monde
      - debug:
          msg: "{{ my_data | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

Give

```
{
  - msg: data: 'hello: world

             bonjour: monde

             '
}
```

Comment: Content of *data* is text. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, its a multiline text. I want it exactly like at the origin form. YAML --> Ansible var --> YAML should give same string isnit?

Comment: Post `ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK` What callback do you use?

Comment: I am using debug task as an example, but the problem also occurs when writing the YAML string into a file.